# Loop to remove all entries which are successively repetitive

Tags: r, loops

[image: Data]

Refer to the picture above. I want to remove all entries which are successively repetitive referencing to only 3rd column.

First it should check 1st and 2nd row, if 3rd column same then delete 2nd row and check 1st and 3rd row and so on. If 3rd column is different for two successive rows then do nothing and increment row to check the next two.

This was the closest I could get.

```
for ( i in 1:2493658) { if (newcol2[i,3]== newcol2[i+1,3]) newcol3 <- newcol2[-c(i+1),] }
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Reproducible example

```
df <- data.frame(Customer=1:6,
                 Invoice=letters[1:6],
                 Sales.Rep.ID=rep(c(10,20),each=3),
                 stringsAsFactors=F)
```

#### dplyr solution

```
library(dplyr)
desired <- df %>%
             mutate(dup = duplicated(Sales.Rep.ID)) %>%
             filter(dup==F) %>%
             select(-dup)
```

#### Output

```
  Customer Invoice Sales.Rep.ID
1        1       a           10
2        4       d           20
```

Comment: So if the Sales.Rep.ID is 10, 20, 10. I don't want to delete the 10 in the third row. Delete only when it occurs consecutively.

Comment: Could you update your original post? You say you want to compare row 1 and 2 first...if the 3rd column is the same, delete row 2...then compare row 1 and 3...if the 3rd column is the same, what should happen?

Comment: delete row 3. The same process continues until you get a different value in row 3 and in that case do nothing and continue the same process again with the next row.

Answer (score 0):

```
newcol3 <- newcol2[cumsum(rle(as.numeric(newcol2[,3]))$lengths),]
newcol4 <- newcol2[cumsum(rle(as.numeric(newcol2[,3]))$lengths)- rle(as.numeric(newcol2[,3]))$lengths +1,]
```

The first one deletes top duplicate values and keeps last while the second one keeps top value and deletes rest.
This is what I was looking for.
Thank you anyway